# Getting error Parameter value [1465] did not match expected type [java.util.Set (n/a)] while fetchimg data from JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am getting Data from MySql using Spring Data JPA. I getting this error when I am passing provider as 1465 in request.

I have tried Sending Set from the request as well.

My calling code is :

```
offerList = blackholeDetailRepository.findByProductVMS(ProductType.VMS, blackholeID,
              pricingCopyRequestBO.getProviderId().longValue(),
              OfferGradeConstant.fromString(pricingCopyRequestBO.getOfferGrade()));
```

Code in repository is :

```
@Query("SELECT detail FROM #{#entityName} AS detail JOIN FETCH detail.vmsRestrictedProviders AS provider "+
          "WHERE detail.product = :product " + "AND detail.master.id= :masterId "
          + "AND detail.vmsRestrictedProviders = :providerId " + "AND provider.offerGrade= :offerGrade")
  Set<BlackholeDetailEntity> findByProductVMS(@Param("product") ProductType product, @Param("masterId") Long masterId,
      @Param("providerId") Long providerId, @Param("offerGrade") OfferGradeConstant offerGrade);
```

BlackholeDetailEntity Entity is :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "blackhole_detail")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class BlackholeDetailEntity extends PolygonDetailEntity {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @CollectionTable(name = "blackhole_entity_mapping",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "detail_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
  @Column(name = "entity_id")
  private Set<Integer> entities;

  @Convert(converter = CsvStringSetConverter.class)
  private Set<String> restrictedOffers;
  
  @Convert(converter = CsvLongSetConverter.class)
  @Column(name = "ll_me_restricted_providers", columnDefinition = "text")
  private Set<Long> llMERestrictedProviders;
  
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
      orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "blackHole")
  private Set<VmsProviderRestrictionEntity> vmsRestrictedProviders;
  
  @Column(name = "is_restrict_all")
  private Boolean restrictAll;
}
```

VmsProviderRestrictionEntity is :

```
@Data
@Entity
@ToString(exclude = {"blackHole"})
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "blackHole")
@Table(name = "vms_provider_blackhole_restriction")
public class VmsProviderRestrictionEntity implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private OfferGradeConstant offerGrade;

  @Convert(converter = CsvLongSetConverter.class)
  @Column(name = "vms_restricted_providers", columnDefinition = "text")
  private Set<Long> providerIds;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "blackhole_id")
  private BlackholeDetailEntity blackHole;
}
```

PolygonDetailEntity.java

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Data
@ToString(exclude = {"master","masterPricing"})
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false, exclude = {"master", "masterPricing"})
public class PolygonDetailEntity extends ModifiableAuditableEntity {
  
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -9100537914314976516L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "master_id")
  private PolygonMasterEntity master;
  
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "master_pricing_id")
  private PolygonMasterPricingEntity masterPricing;
  
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private ProductType product;

  private Integer serviceId;

  @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
  private String comments;

  private String accessTechnology;

  @Column(name = "is_active")
  private Boolean active;

  @Column(name = "is_deleted")
  private Boolean deleted;
}
```

Comment: can you add PolygonDetailEntity.java here?

Comment: @VishalPawar added the entity class

Comment: Is it working for other provider ids?

Comment: No its not working for any provider Id